# Can I add a path into another path?

Tags: objective-c, ios5

Is there a possibility that i can connect 2 or more path? For example, I have an image that is moving in a line, and when I add a line to the line 1, the 2 lines now form the letter L. Is there a possibility that my new object now moves in the new line?.

Comment: So what you want is to take an animating view, that's moving in a certain direction and then have it move in an "L-shaped" direction instead?